# Using ReflectionClass in PHP, how do you use the passed parameters in the constructor?

Tags: php, class, reflection

So I have a class that I want to create with a dynamic amount of parameters (other classes it can use). This is dynamic because the site is fairly dynamic, and if I add a new class/plugin, I want my main class to be able to use it.

This is my code for creating the class:

```
$my_class = 'pages';
$my_parameters = array($class_mysql, $class_functions, $class_forms2);
$my_parameters = array_merge($my_parameters, $extra_classes);

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($my_class);
$class_pages = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($my_parameters);
```

The `$extra_classes` is an array that is created with the class instances of all active plugins that I want my pages class to be able to use.

This is all working fine, but I'm at a loss as to what to do in class file now. Here's what I had originally:

```
class pages {

    protected $class_mysql = null;
    protected $class_functions = null;
    protected $class_forms2 = null;

    public function __construct($mysql_instance, $functions_instance,
    $forms2_instance) {

        $this->class_mysql = $mysql_instance;
        $this->class_functions = $functions_instance;
        $this->class_forms2 = $forms2_instance;

    }

}
```

How do I work the passed dynamic parameters into this? I've been searching but can't find anything that makes sense to me. Even the PHP page on ReflectionClass stops at creating the instance of the class, and doesn't have an example of using the parameters in the class itself. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to answer my own questions... but here's what I came up with after googling for about an hour and stumbling onto `func_get_args()`

```
class pages {

    protected $classes = array();

    public function __construct() {
        if (func_num_args() > 0) {
            $args = func_get_args();
            foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
                $this->classes[get_class($value)] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This does what I needed to do. I can now check `$classes` to see what classes are available for `pages` to use, and can use those classes by using `$this->classes['classname']`.

I don't know if this is the right way of doing this, so if anyone knows please comment. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the arguments as array anyway... why not simply explicitly pass them in as an array...? `new Pages($myParameters)`, `function __construct(array $params) ..`

Comment: @deceze You're right... been at this too long. I have no reason to be using the ReflectionClass at all. Removed it, thanks!

Comment: I'd just like to mention *inversion of control* and *dependency injection* as something you should google, which will ultimately make your life easier.